# Can the serial number printed on the COA sticker of a Sony laptop be used with other Windows 7 install disks?

Tags: windows-7, windows, formatting, reinstall

I want to reinstall Windows 7 on my Sony Vaio laptop using a generic [OEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OEM) Windows 7 disk to avoid Sony's crapware because they're a pain to remove.

However, I've heard mixed results regarding the use of [COA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_Authenticity) product keys on Windows 7 disks not bundled with the computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are talking about the COA sticker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COA to install using an OEM disc, yes.

Bear in mind that for VAIO notebooks, you'll need to follow the Install Order on Sony's support site if you want basically anything on the notebook to work properly (wireless and webcam are the major problems).

Comment: Yes I know. Will test tommorow.